# iOS 9 spotlight search indexing

Tags: ios9, corespotlight

I am Implementing spotlight search for an app, Which is basically holds some location based data,This app not support caching.

I wanted to index some of the items for spotlight, so I am adding it using CoreSpotlight framework. Since we are not caching the data its not possible from our side to delete an item using `deleteSearchableItemsWithIdentifiers:`. Only way I can delete is by deleting all the items `deleteAllSearchableItemsWithCompletionHandler:`

1. What is the maximum number of items that I can index?
2. Does OS automatically delete the indexed item if some threshold exceeds?
3. Do we need to delete it by ourself?

Answer (score 1):

I've added 1400 employees ok only issue is speed. Could be up to a minute to process them all so I did it on backgroundQueue.

names/offices/phone and phone icon/photo.

Adding a separate image for each employee was slow.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit on the number of items.However if you dont provide and expiration date to the CSSearchableItem object the iOS will automatically remove it after a period of time.